# IE9 & Plugins, make it more compact

Tags: plugins, internet-explorer-9

I'm very happy with Internet Explorer 9, finally Microsoft did a good job with a browser, so dont say just use "Chrome, Safari, or FireFox".

What really bugs me, after installing LastPass is that it needs a line just under all the open tabs. Is there anyway to more it up to the same line as the tabs, home, favourites and tools buttons. So it dont use all my screen area.

This is only an issue on my laptop since it runs at a much lower resolution.

Really hope this can be fixed or else ... its a do-over for MS. But IE10 will probably be out in Q1 next year.

Comment: Sheesh... don't you just want your cake & eat it too.  I doubt there's much you can do other than rant on the lastpass forums and see if they'll fix it.  Honestly, IE9 is proof that Microsoft talks a good game about wanting to make a proper web-browser, but still failing miserably.

Comment: This is exactly the type of issue that causes most people to consider that MS do not do a good job with browsers.  Plugins can insert toolbars, and can re-enable toolbars without your consultation.

Comment: Well @TheCompWiz other than the plugin part I like it over any other browser now. But I agree that <= IE8, that was some horrible UI. IE9 is more clean than Chrome in my mind. Paul, then you havent tried IE9, it asks if you want to enabled ANY plugin. It even detects if some are slowing startup time.

Comment: @Syska... it's not difficult to automatically enable/reenable plugins in IE9 with little/no feedback from the user.  They're trying, but fail in too many ways.  That being said... IE9 may look cleaner, but the back-end is a huge tangle of duct-tape & bailing wire trying to keep all the bits semi-working, and despite their claims, does not attempt to 100% adhere to any of the common HTML/CSS/JS standards.

Comment: @TheCompWiz I agree on most parts. This works for me. I want to know the browser that exist on most systems and since I personally love it ... I dont want to use yet another browser if there are no gain for me. There might be for others. If IE10 and auto-update dont make it better, I will switch to an other browser and this problem will go away :-).

Comment: Imho... IE = best windows Chrome installer.